# Jasmine test stuck in an infinite reloading loop

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I am trying to write a unit test to validate that a function is called when a button is clicked. For some reason my test gets stuck in a reloading loop. I have added the html and ts file associated with the test as well as pointed out in one of the comments.

```js
it('should keep the save btn disabled until recording has been done', () => {
  spyOn(component, 'onSave');
  fixture.detectChanges()
  let button = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#createRecording')).nativeElement;
  button.click();
  expect(component.onSave).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(0);
})
```

```html
 
<form [formGroup]="webRecordingForm" (ngSubmit)="onSave()">
<div class="row" style="padding: 20px 10px;">
<div class="col-sm-12">
<!-- <a href="#" id="backToMsgs1" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" style="float: right; margin-left: 5px;" title="Back to Messages">Back<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right"></span></a> -->
<button type="submit" [disabled]="!webRecordingForm.valid" class="btn btn-lg" style="float: right; margin-left: 5px;color: white;background-color:#105b63 ;" id="createRecording"><i class="fa fa-check-circle fa-lg"></i> Save</button>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

ts file

```js
onSave() {
    //console.log("on Save Recordings");
    if (this.record !== undefined || this.record != null) {
      this.OutputSaveRecording.emit("Clicked");
    }
    else {
      alert("No Recording Found");
    }

  }
```

Comment: Can you show the HTML and TypeScript? I am thinking when you're clicking the button, something gets called like a `location.reload()`.

Comment: added the html and typescript @AliF50

Comment: Try removing the `alert('no recording found')` and see if the problem goes away.

Comment: I tried commenting out the alert('no recording found') thank you for the suggestion but it didnt work

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure then.

Answer (score 0):

import ReactiveFormsModule in the TestBed.configureTestingModule.

```
await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [ YourComponent ],
  imports: [ReactiveFormsModule],
  providers: [
    FormBuilder
  ]
})
.compileComponents();
```